# Batch file command to get TFS advanced get specific version with Latest version

Tags: tfs, tfvc, tf-cli

Please let me know the Batch file command to "get TFS advanced get specific with latest version"

Advanced --> Get Specific Version --> Type "Latest Version" --> Overwrite --> Get

Answer (score 3):

You can force a get using:

```
tf vc get /noprompt /recursive /overwrite /version:T path\to\workspace\root
```

To restore deleted files you can add `/all` or replace `/overwrite /all` with `/force`.

See also: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/get-command